# How to create 2 NSGs and assign each to one specific subnet

Tags: azure, terraform

The following code successfully deploys 1 NSG with inbound and outbound rules and attaches to both the app and db subnets specified.

My question is how would I go about creating 2 NSGs (t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-dev-app-nsg and t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-dev-db-nsg) and assigning each one to one specific subnet (App & DB)

Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

**data.tf**

```
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-network-rg"
}

data "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnet" {
  name                = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-vnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}
```

**main.tf**

```
# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

  tenant_id       = "3fa82312-2a80-4dd3-bdaa-e26f5b497f75" # LP tenant ID
  subscription_id = "4813e418-596c-48a3-8a2d-e13a265463a7"

}

module "resource_group" {
  source                       = "../../../modules/terraform-azure-module-resourcegroup"
  create_single_resource_group = false
  single_resource_group_name   = "VOID-HOW TO REMOVE THIS FROM CONFIG?" # Enter ONLY when create_single_resource_group = true
  resource_group_location      = "australiasoutheast"
  resource_group_names         = var.resource_group_names

}

module "subnet" {
  source              = "../../../modules/terraform-azure-module-network/virtual-network/subnet"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  vnet_name           = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
  subnets             = var.subnets
  nsg_id              = module.network_security_group.id
}

module "network_security_group" {
  source              = "../../../modules/terraform-azure-module-network/nsg"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  name                = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-app-nsg"
  inbound_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Inbound_Example1"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    },
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Inbound_Example2"
      priority                   = 101
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Inbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    }
  ]
  outbound_rules = [
    {
      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Outbound_Example1"
      priority                   = 100
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    },
    {

      name                       = "AZ_Allow_Outbound_Example2"
      priority                   = 101
      access                     = "Allow"
      protocol                   = "*"
      direction                  = "Outbound"
      source_port_range          = "*"
      destination_port_range     = "*"
      source_address_prefix      = "VirtualNetwork"
      destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
    }

  ]
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
output "root_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.id
}

output "root_virtual_network_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.id
}

output "root_subnet_names" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_names
}


output "root_subnet_address_prefixes" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_address_prefixes
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = module.subnet.subnet_ids
}

output "nsg_id" {
  value = module.network_security_group.id
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_names" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["Benedict", "Santosh", "Johan", "Jude"]
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    address_prefix = string
  }))
  default = {
    subnet1 = { name = "App", address_prefix = "10.101.80.0/24" }
    subnet2 = { name = "DB", address_prefix = "10.101.81.0/24" }
    # nsg_id          = string
  }
}

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type    = string
  default = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-network-rg"
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
  default     = "australiasoutheast"
}

variable "nsg_name" {
  description = "The name of the network security group"
  type        = string
  default = "t-ause-lp-dev-sandbox-dev-app-nsg"
}
```

**module-subnet-main.tf**

```
# Create the Subnet
resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.value.name
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = var.vnet_name
  address_prefixes     = [each.value.address_prefix]
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "subnet_nsg_association" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.subnet[each.key].id
  network_security_group_id = var.nsg_id
}
```

**module-subnet-variables.tf**

```
# Subnet Variables

variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "vnet_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = map(object({
    name           = string
    address_prefix = string
    # nsg_id          = string
  }))
}

variable "nsg_id" {
  description = "The ID of the Network Security Group"
  type        = string
}
```

**module-subnet-outputs.tf**

```
output "subnet_names" {
  value = { for subnet_key, subnet_value in azurerm_subnet.subnet : subnet_key => subnet_value.name }
}

output "subnet_ids" {
  value = { for k, v in azurerm_subnet.subnet : k => v.id }
}

output "subnet_address_prefixes" {
  value = { for subnet_key, subnet_value in azurerm_subnet.subnet : subnet_key => subnet_value.address_prefixes }
}
```

**module-nsg-main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "nsg" {
  name                = var.name
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  tags                = var.tags

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.inbound_rules
    content {
      name                                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                                   = security_rule.value.priority
      access                                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      direction                                  = "Inbound"
      source_address_prefix                      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      source_address_prefixes                    = security_rule.value.source_address_prefixes
      source_application_security_group_ids      = security_rule.value.source_application_security_group_ids
      source_port_range                          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      source_port_ranges                         = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
      destination_address_prefix                 = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefixes               = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefixes
      destination_application_security_group_ids = security_rule.value.destination_application_security_group_ids
      destination_port_range                     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      destination_port_ranges                    = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges
      description                                = security_rule.value.description
    }
  }

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = var.outbound_rules
    content {
      name                                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                                   = security_rule.value.priority
      access                                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      direction                                  = "Outbound"
      source_address_prefix                      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      source_address_prefixes                    = security_rule.value.source_address_prefixes
      source_application_security_group_ids      = security_rule.value.source_application_security_group_ids
      source_port_range                          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      source_port_ranges                         = security_rule.value.source_port_ranges
      destination_address_prefix                 = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefixes               = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefixes
      destination_application_security_group_ids = security_rule.value.destination_application_security_group_ids
      destination_port_range                     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      destination_port_ranges                    = security_rule.value.destination_port_ranges
      description                                = security_rule.value.description

    }
  }
}
```

**module-nsg-outputs.tf**

```
output "id" {
  value = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.id
}

output "name" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.name
  description = "The name of the network security group."
}

output "resource_group_name" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.resource_group_name
  description = "The name of the resource group in which to create the network security group."
}

output "location" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.location
  description = "The location/region where the network security group is created."
}

output "tags" {
  value       = azurerm_network_security_group.nsg.tags
  description = "The tags assigned to the resource."
}
```

**module-nsg-variables.tf**

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "location" {
  type        = string
  description = "location of resource group"
}

variable "name" {
  type        = string
  description = "The name of the network security group."
}

variable "tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  default     = {}
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to the resource."
}

variable "inbound_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                                       = string
    priority                                   = number
    access                                     = string
    protocol                                   = string
    direction                                  = string
    source_address_prefix                      = optional(string)
    source_address_prefixes                    = optional(list(string))
    source_application_security_group_ids      = optional(list(string))
    source_port_range                          = optional(string)
    source_port_ranges                         = optional(list(string))
    destination_address_prefix                 = optional(string)
    destination_address_prefixes               = optional(list(string))
    destination_application_security_group_ids = optional(list(string))
    destination_port_range                     = optional(string)
    destination_port_ranges                    = optional(list(string))
    description                                = optional(string)
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "List of objects that represent the configuration of each inbound rule."
}

variable "outbound_rules" {
  type = list(object({
    name                                       = string
    priority                                   = number
    access                                     = string
    protocol                                   = string
    source_address_prefix                      = optional(string)
    source_address_prefixes                    = optional(list(string))
    source_application_security_group_ids      = optional(list(string))
    source_port_range                          = optional(string)
    source_port_ranges                         = optional(list(string))
    destination_address_prefix                 = optional(string)
    destination_address_prefixes               = optional(list(string))
    destination_application_security_group_ids = optional(list(string))
    destination_port_range                     = optional(string)
    destination_port_ranges                    = optional(list(string))
    description                                = optional(string)
  }))
  default     = []
  description = "List of objects that represent the configuration of each outbound rule."
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried provisioning two NSGs and one specified subnet for each NSG using terraform and I was able to provision the requriement sucessfully.

The code you provided has some problems with creating two Network Security Groups (NSGs) and assigning each to a specific subnet in Azure. Your current setup only allows for a single NSG. To fix this, you need to change the configuration to make two different NSGs and link each one to the corresponding subnet (App and DB).

Here's a step-by-step guide to modify your Terraform configuration:

1. **Define Two NSGs in the `module-nsg-main.tf` File**:

   - You need to create two separate NSG resources with distinct names.
   - The names can be passed as variables or hard-coded.
2. **Modify Subnet Configuration in `module-subnet-main.tf`**:

   - Update the `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association` resource to associate each subnet with its corresponding NSG.
   - You will have to pass the NSG IDs as variables to this module.
3. **Update Variables**:

   - Add variables for the names and IDs of the two NSGs.
   - Update the subnet configuration to include which NSG it should be associated with.
4. **Outputs**:

   - Modify outputs to include the IDs and other relevant information for both NSGs.

I tried a demo configuration to provision your end requirement.

**terraform configuration:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demovk-sbrg"
  location = "East US"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "demosb-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

variable "subnets" {
  description = "List of subnet names"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["app", "DB"] # Add your subnet names here
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  count                = length(var.subnets)
  name                 = var.subnets[count.index]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.${count.index}.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
  count               = length(var.subnets)
  name                = "${var.subnets[count.index]}-nsg"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  dynamic "security_rule" {
    for_each = [
      {
        name                       = "inbound-rule"
        priority                   = 100
        direction                  = "Inbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "80"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      },
      {
        name                       = "outbound-rule"
        priority                   = 200
        direction                  = "Outbound"
        access                     = "Allow"
        protocol                   = "Tcp"
        source_port_range          = "*"
        destination_port_range     = "80"
        source_address_prefix      = "*"
        destination_address_prefix = "*"
      }
    ]
    content {
      name                       = security_rule.value.name
      priority                   = security_rule.value.priority
      direction                  = security_rule.value.direction
      access                     = security_rule.value.access
      protocol                   = security_rule.value.protocol
      source_port_range          = security_rule.value.source_port_range
      destination_port_range     = security_rule.value.destination_port_range
      source_address_prefix      = security_rule.value.source_address_prefix
      destination_address_prefix = security_rule.value.destination_address_prefix
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  count                     = length(var.subnets)
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.example[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.example[count.index].id
}
```

here by providing the list of subnets we can specify the no of nsg need to provision according to the requirement.

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I ran a tfplan after demoing your solution, now I'm getting the following error, how can I fix this.                                  `│ Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on ..\..\..\modules\terraform-azure-module-network\virtual-network\subnet\main.tf line 29, in resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "subnet_nsg_association":  
│   29:   network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.subnet_nsg_association[count.index].id
│
│ A managed resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "subnet_nsg_association" has not been declared in module.subnet.`

Comment: Go to the file subnet\main.tf and look for the resource azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association. Verify that the network_security_group_id attribute is referencing a valid and correctly named NSG resource.

Verify NSG Resource: In the module where you expect the NSG resource to be declared, check if it's correctly defined. If it's missing, add it. If it's incorrectly named, correct it.

Comment: Cross-Module References: If you're referencing an NSG resource from another module, ensure the reference is correct. For example, if the NSG is defined in a module named nsg_module, the reference should be something like module.nsg_module.azurerm_network_security_group.subnet_nsg_association[count.index].id.

Comment: Thanks Vinay, I will loop back to this at a later date and re-post if there's further issues